# Visual Studio 2013 - VB.NET MVC 5 Template

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

I cannot locate a vb.net MVC5 Template in VS2013 Ultimate (just installed).

Comment: Please Add comment on Downvotes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An important thing to remember is that ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013 has migrated to "One ASP.NET" which consists of a single Web Application environment that supports all of the major development technologies (*Web Forms, MVC, Web API, etc.*).

You'll just need to follow these steps to set up an MVC5 application in Visual Basic :

1. Create a New Project.
2. Choose the ASP.NET Web Application (*ensure that the Web tab is selected under Visual Basic templates within Visual Studio*)
3. In the dialog that appears, select the MVC template.
4. Click Ok to create your MVC application.

You should see something like this in the image below :

[image: One ASP.NET Example]

As far as an explicit MVC5 template, I'm not sure a template is currently available in Visual Studio 2013 (*since it uses the One ASP.NET approach*) however you may want to consider downloading the **[ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 Update for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)** which adds the MVC5 Templates in Visual Studio 2012 and would allow you to explicitly use an MVC5 Template within Visual Studio 2012 :

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

Answer (score 2):

- Click **New Project**, then select **Visual Basic** on the left and select **Web**.
- Verify that you have selected **.NET Framework 4.5** from the drop down list up top.
- Below the framework drop down list, select **ASP.NET Web Application**. Name your project whatever you wish and then click **OK**.
- In the **New ASP.NET Project** dialog, click **MVC** and then click **OK**.

Your ASP.NET MVC 5 VB.NET web project should now load up.

---

> Note: I do not believe the preview version of Visual Studio 2013 came with the VB.NET template.